# lambda calculus in some type system

Tags: lambda-calculus

look at my system type (rules of them):
$$\frac{\Gamma(x:\tau)\vdash e:\rho}{\Gamma(x:\tau)\vdash \lambda x .e:\tau\rightarrow\rho}$$
$$\frac{\Gamma\vdash e_1:\tau\rightarrow\rho\ \ \ \ \ \Gamma\vdash e_2\rightarrow \tau}{\Gamma\vdash e_1e_2 : \rho}$$

$$\frac{}{\Gamma\vdash n:\text{int}}$$
$$\frac{}{\Gamma(x:\tau)\vdash x:\tau}$$

$$(\lambda x.e)e' \rightarrow ^{\beta} e[x:=e]$$

And types:
$$\tau ::= \text{int}|\tau_1 \rightarrow \tau_2$$
Possible expressions:
$$e::=x|n|e_1e_2|\lambda x.e$$
Now, I am trying to find some examples:
a) untypable expresssion: $(\lambda x.xx)$. It was fairly easy.
However, I am not sure about b)

b) $e$ should by untypable. $e', e \rightarrow ^{\beta} e'$ should be typable. Moreover, all variables in lambda expressions should be binded by lambda.

The only way that I see is:
$e = \lambda x.xx$ - untypable.
$e' = \lambda x.x$ - typable.
$e \rightarrow ^{\beta} e' = \lambda x.x(\lambda x.x)$ seems to be typable.

What do you think about it ? Maybe, someone can give other example (assuming that my examples are correct).

**Edit, second example**
Give example of typable expressions $e, e'$ and type $\tau$ such that there are fullfilled three conditions:
(a) $e\rightarrow ^{\beta} e'$
(b) $e'$ is type of $\tau$
(c) $e$ is not type of $\tau$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e = \lambda x. x x$ does *not* reduce to $\lambda x. x(\lambda x. x)$. $e$ is an abstraction: remember the convention says $\lambda x. x x$ is syntactic sugar for $(\lambda x. (x\ x))$. Note that under [full $\beta$-reduction strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction_strategies) we could try reducing the body of the abstraction, but in our case the body of $e$ does not contain a [redex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction) (reducible expression).

If we are allowed to use integer literals, then
$$(\lambda x. 0)\ (0\ 0)$$
is not well-typed, but it reduces (under the call-by-name strategy) to $0$, which has type $\mathsf{int}$.

Another example, which does not use any integer literals:
$$
(\lambda z. (\lambda y. y))\ (\lambda x. x\ x) \to_\beta (\lambda y. y)[z := (\lambda x. x\ x)] = (\lambda y. y)
$$
is not well-typed because the argument of the application is not well-typed, but it reduces in one step to $\lambda y. y$, which (for example) can be assigned the type $\mathsf{int} \to \mathsf{int}$.

As for your last example, it is impossible to find such two *well-typed* expressions $e$ and $e'$ with the properties $e\rightarrow ^{\beta} e'$ and $\mathrm{typeof}(e) \ne \mathrm{typeof}(e')$.
Your system looks very much like a simply-typed lambda calculus (with implicit types) enhanced with integers. There is the preservation theorem for STLC:
$$
\Gamma \vdash e : \tau \;  \wedge \; e \to_\beta e' \implies \Gamma \vdash e' : \tau ,
$$
which does not let you find the desired $e$ and $e'$.

The preservation theorem is covered in the [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) book by B.C. Pierce.

Comment: I edited my first post. Could you look again - I added additional example.  Second thing: Could you show me why this second example reduces to $\lambda y.y$ ?

Comment: @HaskellFun I've updated the answer. $z$ is not present in the body of the corresponding abstraction, so the substitution is really simple - just throw away the argument and return the body.